# Anonymous function causing ids to not be set after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, ajax, anonymous-function

I'm making an AJAX call from within an Anonymous function. When the success callback takes place I'm then able to set my custom JS objects ids and other important info that has arrived from the data server.

After I set the a.target.id to the returned data.id everything looks fine.

On the step where I'm calling a function to do some work with the newly updated custom JS object, that I just updated with the response data from the server. I am passing the parent of that object to the method to do some work on all the children of that object.

However, as you can see on the last example in the snap shot photos the a.target.parent.children[0].id is not in the collection and/or it's ids where never set.

I must be losing a reference to that object during the AJAX call when using an Anonymous function.

Here is all of the code. How am I losing the reference? Or how can I maintain a reference to that parent's children when the AJAX call returns?

I've never had this happen before, makes me believe that it has something to do with the Anonymous function.

```
var horizontalPositioner = function (horizontals) {

    var hpa = ['?horPositions='];

    for (var i = 0; i < horizontals.children.length; i += 1) {

        hpa.push(horizontals.children[i].id + ':' + horizontals.children[i].position + ',');
    };

    hpa[i] = hpa[i].replace(',', '');

    dataBase.update(dbPart('horizontal' + hpa.join('')));
};


this.subscribe.call(this, e.horizontaladded, function (a, fn) {
    //
    if (!a.extra.owner.id) {
        return;
    };

    (function (a) {

        dataBase.insert(
            dbPart(
            ['horizontal?a=', a.extra.owner.instanceName, '&id=', a.extra.owner.id].join(''),
            a.target
            ),
            dbCB(
            function (data, status) {
                if (status === 'error') { return; };

                a.target.id = data.id,
                a.target.HTML().addClass('alum_' + data.id),
                a.target.finish.id = data.finishID,
                a.target.size.id = data.sizeID,
                a.target.siteLine.id = data.sitelineID;
                //
                //reposition horizontals
               // setTimeout(function () { horizontalPositioner(a.target.parent); }, 1000);
                debugger
                horizontalPositioner(a.target.parent);

                if (fn) { processCallbacks(data, status, fn); };


                //very last
                events.publishDatabaseCallbacks(e.horizontaladded,
                    eArgs(a.bay, { data: data, instanceName: 'horizontal', ownerid: a.extra.owner.id, id: data.id }));

            },
            function (xhr, status, errorThrown) { console.log('ERROR adding horizontal'); })
        );

    }(a));

}, true);
```

[image: Snap shot of the three steps]

Comment: Not looking at `a.target`?

Answer (score 0):

I've added an anonymous function with a nested setTimeout to give everything time to build. I've got many events taking place at once, so for now this works.

```
var horizontalPositioner = function (horizontals) {

    (function (hors) {

        setTimeout(function () {

            var hpa = ['?horPositions='];

            for (var i = 0; i < hors.children.length; i += 1) {
                hpa.push(hors.children[i].id + ':' + (hors.children[i].position ? hors.children[i].position : 1) + ',');
            };

            hpa[i] = hpa[i].replace(',', '');

            dataBase.update(dbPart('horizontal' + hpa.join('')));

        }, 1000);

    }(horizontals));
};
```